# How Do DVRs for remote vieiwing work

Tags: remote-access, dvr

I may be posting in the wrong place here but I am thinking of developing a software solution to send images from digital cameras to a mobile phone.

I have seen DVRs with 4-8 channels selling as kits. They allow remote access viewing via a mobile device.

How are the images streamed from plugged in DVR to router to mobile work?

Is the normal practice to use a DNS to go type of service?

Is this type of service reliable?  If we assume that the internet connection is OK are the images reliable to view in real-time on a mobile phone?

Can multiple users access the same stream using this current solution/offering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will use some kind of [streaming protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_media#Protocols), there is a very large range to choose from. Anything from [actual video streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264) to [sending a series of still images in stream form.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG)

Just pick a standard that will be easily supported on your target platforms and learn how to send and receive data when them.

Comment: hi, thanks for your thoughts. I may have worded my question badly :) I know I can stream and i am via still images  ina compressed format (and this suits me)  But would they use a peer-2-peer between the DVR-router-mobile device.  Is it a reliable service?

Comment: @AndrewSimpson its as reliable as the ability for your users to set up firewall port forwarding to the service (or your service's ability to open ports via UPnP). And it would not be peer to peer, this is a classic client server design, the software generating the images is the server the mobile devices is the client. If you don't want the chance that firewalls will "screw up" the connection you can host and pay for a central server that the image software can "push" to and the mobile clients "pull" from. That also fixes the DNS because you only need the proxy server's address on the clients.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that.  I agree with everything you say and the 'push' 'pull' approach is the way forward for me. Many Thanks